# Angular 2+: how to subscribe to form valueChanges of whitelisted fields?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

I've a **big form** and would like to **listen to the changes of** 5 **specific fields**.

I can listend to the entire form:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
    // do something, because any field changed
});
```

or to a single field:

```
this.form.get('my_single_field').valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
    // do something, because my_single_field changed
});
```

**Desired:**

but I would like to have something like:

```
this.form.get(['field1', 'field5']).valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
    // do something, because field1 or field5 changed
});
```

or:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(data, changedField => {
    // do something, because changedField changed
});
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

You can add below function as prototype on Form.

**Previous**:

Use [merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) from rxjs. Function should be like this.

```
function listenChangesOn(form,fields:string[]){
  return Observable.merge(fields.map(field=>form.get(field).valueChanges))
}
```

and can use like

```
listenChangesOn(form,['field1','field2']).subscribe(a=>..)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've put your solution in the `ngOnInit()`, but it fires only one time (on init). Could you please give me an example, wrapped in a class? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue. I wanted to listen the entire form except one field, and solved by listening the entire form as you do, and inside the observer function put a conditional asking if this field is touched. Would be something like this:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
   if (this.form.controls['field1'].touched) return;

// do something, because any other field changed
});
```

Of course you can do the inverse way, by listening the specific fields you need.